# JPA EntityManager : save objects only when explicitly requested

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin, entitymanager

I'm fairly new to Hibernate and JPA, and am currently working on an application that uses it through JPA's EntityManager.

When looking at some basic hibernate tutorials using Hibernate session, I see that I can do :

```
val session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
session.beginTransaction()
val coordinates = session.find(Coordinates::class.java, "12345")
coordinates.longitude = 0.0
session.save(coordinates)
session.getTransaction().commit()
```

When using Entitymanager, it's done this way :

```
val em = emFactory.createEntityManager()
em.transaction.begin()
val coordinates = em.find(Coordinates::class.java, "12345")
coordinates.longitude = 0.0
em.transaction.commit()
```

The main difference here is that using EntityManager, I don't have to explicitly make a call to a `save` function to actually update the object, which will be flushed eventually during commit. Of course, I coul do something like

```
if(obj.id == null) {
    return em.merge()
} else {
    val saved = em.persist(obj)
    return saved
}
```

But what's the point for already existing objects if they get saved anyway, no matter if I call this or not ?

Surprisingly, the [examples](https://thorben-janssen.com/implementing-the-repository-pattern-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) found around here seem to rely on a save method as well.

My question is : is there a way to configure EntityManager to update the objects only when requested specifically (i.e. mimick session behavior) ? Or do I have to use Session to achieve this ?

Comment: The idea of an entity manager is that he, as his name suggests, manages entities (that are tied to the transaction the entity manager lives in). Maybe you need to explain your actual problem to enable us understanding what you want to achieve instead of asking about technicalities of JPA. `merge` on an EM can be used to e. g. re-attach entities to a session without you needing to reload the entity and populate the fields based on the detached entity.

Comment: I get that, of course. My problem is exactly the one I described : I am requested to save entities only when asked to (i.e. a call to a save method, meaning that a modified entity should be discarded if not explicitly saved). I'm trying to estimate if I can have a quick fix using the existing EntityManager or if I have to switch to using Session, which will cost a bit more.

Comment: Why do you change entities if you don't want them changed? ;-) An easy way to "break out" of a request discarding all changes in JEE is throwing a `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` which, as its parameter suggests, causes the transaction to be rolled back.

Comment: But nevertheless my point is still valid: You haven't mentioned _why_ you want to discard a change on an entity, only that you want that possibility.

Comment: In fact thre are several reasons : there are some cases where entities get modified but then some business rules come up that require those changes to be discarded (you can question the validity of the code structure, but for now it is written this way). Another point is that this code comes from an app that didn't use an RDBMS in the first place (but a nosql datastore), that had no notion of persistence context whatsoever. All this has been abstracted behind regular CRUD calls, so I was asked to look into keeping the same behavior if possible. But I guess this answers my question :)

Answer (score 1):

`merge` is the opportunity for the EntityManager to actually perform database operations. Merging, persisting, flushing, and committing are essentially all contact points with the database.

For simple cases, you can simply rely on changing the behavior at commit and not physically merge yourself, but many like the control knowing when it will actually happen. Knowing that "after this, it's in the DB". Because after the merge, not only is the data persisted, along with any cascading behavior, but also any side effects from triggers etc. on the DB have happened as well.

They're not committed, but they've happened. Keys are assigned for parents and children, triggers have fired, lifecycle methods have fired, everything is "as it should be", "right now", vs "sometime in the future" even if that may only be milliseconds away.

Comment: I know all that, but thanks for the very clear explanation :)